# Difference between routing inside v-btn and using router-link

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am learning Vue.js, and, following a tutorial, a  is used to route the page to another. He used a button wrapped by this  tag, and I found that using the routing directive inside the  tag. 
   I was wondering, what's the difference between this two ways of going from one page to another? Both of them seems to be producing the same behavior (and I am not sending or receiving any data when changing pages).

Codes for comparison:

Using **v-btn**

```
<v-btn :to="{name: 'songs-create'}" 
      dark medium right bottom fab absolute 
      class="pink" slot="action">
        <v-icon>add</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
```

Using **router-link**

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'Hello'}" tag="span" class="logo">Tab Tracker</router-link>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should be `:to="\`{name: 'songs-create'}\`"`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`v-btn` is a component of [vuetifyjs](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/buttons#api) whereas `router-link` is component of [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html).

When you use `v-btn` with `to` attribute by passing the path object, it internally uses the vue-router's router-link component's api.

So v-btn wraps the functionality of router-link when it is used with `to` attribute.

The reason why he could have been used the `v-btn` is to accomplish some other stuff like button styles and handling other events etc.

Comment: Thanks mate, I hadn't realized v-btn was a Vuetifyjs component! But it's good to know it can wrap the functionality of router-link, I can now save some lines on my vue components whenever I need a button!

Comment: glad my answer helped you!